# Wo kann man den Unterschied zwischen Synonymen nachgucken?

Tags: synonym, resource

Seit langem poste ich Fragen über die Unterschiede zwischen manchen Wörtern.

Gibt es irgendwelche guten Quellen, in denen man sie prüfen kann?

Comment: So einfach ist das gar nicht, weil die Unterschiede manchmal sehr subtil sind und manchmal ist es einfach nur, dass in dem einen Satz zwei Wörter ausgetauscht werden können und in einem anderen nicht. Oder bestimmte Wortkollokationen. Das effektivste ist aber eigene Recherche: Wörter verstehen, ihre typischen Anwendungsgebiete analysieren und das ganze dann verinnerlichen.

Comment: Soweit die Frage hier zulässig (on-topic) ist, wirst Du wahrscheinlich von lebendigen Forumteilnehmern bessere Antworten erhalten als von irgendwann gedruckten Listen.

Answer (score 1):

[Woxikon](http://synonyme.woxikon.de) führt zwar keine Unterschiede auf, aber wenn man dort nach den Synonymen für ein bestimmtes Wort sucht, werden die gefundenen Synonyme nach Bedeutungen geclustert. Sucht man beispielsweise nach Synonymen für »Leiter«, werden die Ergebnisse in 17 verschiedene Bedeutungscluster gruppiert. Das hilft schon sehr, wenn man erkennen will, inwiefern eines der angezeigten Synonyme mit dem Ursprungswort übereinstimmt.

Außerdem kann man dort auf jeden Treffer klicken, und bekommt dann die Synonyme dieses Treffers angezeigt.